# IntelliJ IDEA Editor Replace Function Doesn't Work But Replace Does

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a work item that I have to replace some words with other words in many files.

When I press the combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, the replace window shows. I type some words and then click the "replace" button, but it dosesn't work. But if I click "Replace All" button, the "Clear Read-only Status" window shows and I click OK button. All file all been edited and added to a change list.

Why the "replace button" failed, but "replace ALL button" worked.

My version is: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.2 (Community Edition)

Comment: Why do you edit files that are read-only in the first place?

Comment: I mean that click "replace button" did not pop out a "Clear Read-only Status" window, but click "replace all button" did.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I am not sure how many files that I have to do the repalce job. so I want use the replace function do find all files contain the word.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. Read-only files are supposed to be read-only. If your goal is to modify them, why are they read-only? Why don't you make them all writable and then start using your IDE? Why are they read-only in the first place?

Comment: When i click "replece all button", IDEA trigger "Clear Read-only Status"   and then all file been replaced.
But "replece button" did not trigger

Comment: Yes, so? That still doesn't answer my question. I'm done now, since you refuse to answer.

Comment: I upvoted all @JBNizet 's comments, downvoted the question, due to the ugly reply of question owner. The replies made my day.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in IntelliJ IDEA, I have submitted [a bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-205042).